# Is it possible to set a bean name using annotations in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, spring-bean

I have a bean like this:

```
@Bean
public String myBean(){
    return "My bean";
}
```

I want to autowire it:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myBean")
public void setMyBean(String myBean){
    this.myBean=myBean;
}
```

I need something like:

```
@Bean(name="myCustomBean")
```

Is it possible to use custom names names for beans out of the box? If it isn't possible out of the box then how to create such a bean?

Comment: The `@Bean` annotation already indeed has a `name` attribute, so why are you asking "I need something like ..."? This already exists.

Comment: But it's still the same. `@Bean(name = "...")` already exists. If that's not what you mean, then what *do* you mean? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Jesper Sorry, I haven't known that this functionality was introduced in the 4th version of Spring. I should update it

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure) Have a nice evening! :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What you are asking is **already available** in Spring [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming)

> By default, configuration classes use a @Bean method’s name as the
> name of the resulting bean. This functionality can be overridden,
> however, with the name attribute.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myFoo")
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I think I have not clear question. I wanted to use custom names.
Also, you can not use @Component annotations on methods.

Comment: @Noel Yap, I retained that 'extra information' to remember how spring evolved on this. That's why I strike-out that text. Could you please re-add? Thanks.

Comment: IMO such history doesn't belong in this answer. For example, I almost missed the actual answer since I almost stopped reading after the first few sentences. Foremost to consider is the purpose of SO and the primary problem those using it are trying to solve.

Comment: Alternatively, the original, legacy answer could have been kept and a new, more up-to-date one created.